# Can only one error / success function be assigned for AngularJS $http promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm trying to do the following:

```
$http.get('..').error(someFunc).error(someFunc2);
```

However it doesn't appear to be working, I get various errors.

I thought it was possible to chain multiple methods in this way? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should describe your various errors.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, $http has specific methods `success()` and `error()`, which are not present on general purpose promises.

Comment: :), for reference see [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http).

Comment: The issue does appear to be beyond the given snippet. Each call to `.error()` [returns the modified `promise`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.1.5/src/ng/http.js#L714-L719), so another call to `.error()` should be fine. http://jsfiddle.net/HMsCa/

Answer (score 3):

If you do :

```
$http.get('..').error(someFunc).error(someFunc2);
```

someFunc2 will ***only*** fire if someFunc throws an error. This is in line with the code snippet that Jonathan Lonowski pointed out : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.1.5/src/ng/http.js#L714-L719

If you want to run multiple functions you can do:

```
$http.get('..').error(function () {someFunc();someFunc2();});
```

Comment: Yes. Only if someFunc succeeds will someFunc2 get called :)

Comment: @ClickUpvote you could do it with `then` take a look to latest answer

Comment: No it does not. Please read the code that you linked to again.

Answer (score 1):

More elegant way using [promise chaining](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).
For error only handling:

`$q.all($http.get('..')).catch(function(errorReason) {...}).catch(function(errorReason) {...})`

For success/error handling:

`$q.all($http.get('..')).then(function(response) {...}, function(errorReason) {...}).then(function(response) {...}, function(errorReason) {...})`

Answer (score 0):

> However it doesn't appear to be working

Yes, it does work. But notice that the [`error`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L919) method works so that your snippet is equivalent to

```
var promise = $http.get('..');
promise.error(someFunc);
promise.error(someFunc2);
```

If you expected chaining behaviour, where `someFunc2` catches only the errors thrown in `someFunc`, use the `.catch()` method instead of `.error()`.